# What is the go_package option used for in a protocol buffer file?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I did some research including looking at the official doc from google and I can't find a good explanation of what the `go_package` option is used for. The official doc states the following:

> The `.proto` file should contain a go_package option specifying the full import path of the Go package that contains the generated code.

I guess what i'm confused with is what they mean by import path. It sounds more like an export path as in where we want to place the generated code? But why would we need this if we can specify the out path during `--go_out=`? So i'm having trouble grasping why you need to specify an export path in the proto file and at the same time specify an output path in `option go_package`?

Comment: "Import path" is the path another package would use to import the generated code, e.g. `github.com/me/myproject/model` or wherever you want it.

Comment: This is the top result in google for the `option go_package golang` and I gotta be honest I'm disappointed in the Go community for this one. Seems really weird and unGo to just add complexity to the language like this without being really clear about all the components of it. Where are these "option" things defined?

Comment: Totally agree @voutasaurus. For people still finding this, the built-in `option`s for protobuf are defined in their `descriptor.proto` file and are interpreted by `protoc`, the tool that builds proto files.

The docs have a cryptic "See `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto`" but it does look like the docstrings in that file are helpful for understanding the default options.
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/c7d2a97879957e1018877cf703e0c0b15f33886f/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto#L392

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring the generated codes expected import path is important for other protobuf files to know how to refer to those types in the generated code.

If all of your protobuf definitions are declared in a single `.proto` file, the import path means little because they are implicitly sharing the same go package. If you start storing/generating protobuf files in multiple packages, they need to know how to find each other.

Looking at the protobuf "Well Known" types is a good example of this:

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto

The top of that file has the following package declaration:

```
option go_package = "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb";
```

If I consume that message in another protobuf file using:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message MyModel {
   google.protobuf.Timestamp ts = 1;
}
```

My generated file for `MyModel` will contain an import statement at the top of the `.pb.go` file that looks like:

```
import timestamppb "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb"
```

Comment: I understand your answer but why would they specify `"google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb"` if the import you're explicitly writing is `"google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"`, this is non trivial at all.

Comment: The `go_package` option declared in the `timestamp.proto` file is broadcasting that the go generated code for that file will be published in that package.

That lets generated code for a proto that imports `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto` know that the `go` generated code should import that package as `google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb`

Comment: Probably a very dumb question, but I still don't understand why you used `"google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"` to import a package that explicitly says that import me using `"google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb"`?